# In which of Einstein's papers did he first propose interpreting square of light wave amplitude as probability of detecting photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, probability, history, specific-reference

In Max Born's Nobel lecture, he alludes to Einstein's proposed interpretation of EM wave amplitude (squared) as being the probability of detecting a photon:  "Again an idea of Einstein’s gave me the lead. He had tried to make the duality of particles - light quanta or photons - and waves comprehensible by interpreting the square of the optical wave amplitudes as probability density for the occurrence of photons."

In which of his papers did Einstein first propose that interpretation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily about history of physics, rather than physics itself.

Comment: The question is not motivated by historical interest.  Rather, the reason for the question is to read the original assertion in order to discern any nuance in meaning it might have conveyed.

But if you think that perhaps "History of Science and Mathematics" is a more appropriate place to pose the question and get the desired answer, then certainly I'll post it there.

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: This would be better for hsm.stackexchange.

Comment: Seems perfect use of [tag:specific-reference] to me

Comment: Posted it to hsm and received very helpful answer there.

Thanks again for guidance in that direction.

Comment: I agree with @KyleKanos, but, given the information it's already been answered in HSM, I'm voting to Leave Closed.

Comment: Answered [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/9972/3844) on hsm.stackexchange